# Keyboard shortcut for sent mail folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> navigates to the "inbox" folder in Microsoft Outlook. Similarly, which keyboard shortcut can be used to navigate to the "sent items" folder?

Answer (score 2):

We can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to open the "Go to folder" pop-up. 
You can navigate from there to the "sent" folder.

Comment: <ctrl><shift><O> to go to **O**utbox. This should be the sent items folder.

Answer (score 2):

There is no [built-in shortcut](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-3cdeb221-7ae5-4c1d-8c1d-9e63216c1efd#bkmk_mail) available for Sent Items folder. If you are familiar with VBA code, you may refer to the code shared in the TechNet thread below:

[shortcut key to check the 'sent emails' but not 'outbox' on Outlook.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2bf472d5-c666-41b2-9902-d41a03e6fba5/shortcut-key-to-check-the-sent-emails-but-not-outbox-on-outlook?forum=outlook)

Comment: any shortcut for favorites folders ?